# misspelling problem of "SetUpTestCase" or "TearDownTestCase"

Tags: googletest

I was wondering if there would be some kind of warning or something for misspelling `SetUpTestCase` (or `TearDownTestCase`)

I was facing a memory leak but also I had deleted all the allocated memory in the `TearDownTestCase` and it was making no sense. After a lot of searches I figured out it is just because of the spelling. I just had wrote it `SetUpTestcase` insted of `SetUpTestCase`!

```
static SetUpTestCase
{
    // allocate some memory
}

static TearDownTestcase // instead of TearDownTestCase 
{
    // delete allocated memory
}
```

Here I've corrected the mistake but isn't there something to be done in order to face a warning, error, etc. when something like  that happens? For example for `SetUp` (because it's a virtual function) we can place a `override` and if some similar misspelling happen, compiler will warn. But in the  `SetUpTestCase/TearDownTestCase` situation (Because the functions are static) this solution can't be used.

Comment: Some compilers like GCC do suggest alternative names in case of spelling mistakes. See this example: https://godbolt.org/z/4wItEY